# LINQ query to select records from table where 2 columns have max values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following data in sql server table:

```
EmployeeId  ForMonth    ForYear     Value   
1           1           2015        45000.00
1           6           2015        35000.00
1           12          2014        66666.00
2           1           2015        70000.00
2           5           2015        80000.00
```

I need to find the LINQ-to-SQL query to select for each EmployeeId the record having max ForMonth and max ForYear.
So the result should be:

```
EmployeeId  ForMonth    ForYear     Value   
1           6           2015        35000.00
2           5           2015        80000.00
```

It's not that I didn't try to solve this before coming and posting this question, but the problem is that I didn't know how to write this query in SQL server, so I don't have any LINQ code to add.
Please if you find this a bad question, ask me to delete it.

Comment: I have a dream that down voters start to have the kindness to say at least why did they down voted a question and caused points loss for a user :/

Comment: Of course I tried, but I have no decent code to post, I have a problem in figuring out how to write the query in sql server, so I don't have something to write in LINQ.

Comment: Ok I'll try and update my question with what I get, Or would you recommend to delete it for now?

Comment: try solution in answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want 1 record per employee, so you need to group by the ID. Then you order your groups by the lastest year/month and select the first one

```
var query = from e in db.Employees
            group e by e.EmployeeId into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(e => e.ForYear)
                    .ThenByDescending(e => e.ForMonth)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elegant and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the record with the greatest `ForYear` and greatest `ForMonth`

```
var result = (from db in MYDBContext
             orderby db.ForYear descending, db.ForMonth descending
             select db).First();
```